# Count() returns 1 result when there is no record in Results view

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

```
 var user = await context.Customers
                .Include(x => x.CustomerPreferences)
                .ThenInclude(up => up.CustomerNations)
                .Where(x => x.Id == userId).FirstOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken);
```

CustomerNations Entity has

```
public Customer Customer { get; set; } = null!;
public virtual IList<CustomerNation> CustomerNations { get; set; } = new List<CustomerNation>();
```

I have no record in CustomerNation table. However, according to this code, there is one record in CustomerNations. When I observe it during debug, Result view shows 0 results.

```
var preferences= user.preferences
                .ToList();

if (preferences.Any())
{
    var customerNations= user.CustomerPreferences
        .Select(x => x.CustomerNations);

    if (customerNations.Count() != 0) //Both, Any() and Count shows there is one record. I check dropdown and Result view has 0 results.
    {
        foreach (var nation in customerNations)
        {
            context.Remove(counterParty);
        }
    }
}
```

Count is 1 but result view says diffent
[image]

Comment: That loop does not make much sense to me: `foreach (var nation in customerNations) { context.Remove(counterParty);  }`

Comment: Your code as posted doesn't seem to make sense as you are setting the "nations" variable and then checking/looping through "customerNations". Where does that come from?

Comment: @JohnM Sorry. Corrected it. To summarize,  if (customerNations.Count() != 0)  is true when there is no record in customerNations

Comment: What is customerNations ? It isn't defined in the code you have shown.

Comment: @sgmoore replaced the word 'populations' with 'user.CustomerNations'. Initially renamed variables and I left a typo.

Comment: Hard to tell what the current instruction is when you observed that result in your debugger.  Also hard to tell which variable you're observing.  Perhaps you're making a false diagnosis with your debugger?  What's the parent object of Results View in that screenshot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Enumerable.Select<TSource,TResult>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select) returns an `IEnumerable<TResult>`. In this case, since `CustomerPreferences.CustomerNations` is of type `IList<CustomerNation>`, `user.CustomerPreferences.Select(x => x.CustomerNations)` is returning an `IEnumerable<IList<CustomerNation>>`. So, your `customerNations` probably has one item which itself is an empty `IList<CustomerNation>`.

If you want to flatten all of the `CustomerNation` instances into a `IEnumerable<CustomerNation>` you should use [`Enumerable.SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany).

`var customerNations = user.CustomerPreferences.SelectMany(x => x.CustomerNations)`